# Passing **kwargs to Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to build custom django form for changing username and user email for an application. That's why I need to pass the user details from the session to a form in order to check if the logged user exists. I am doing in this way:

in views.py

```
personal_info_form = PersonalInfoForm(prefix='personal_info',
                                      user_details=user_details)
```

where `user_details` is a dictionary:

```
'user_details': [{'username': u'username', 
                  'registration_date': datetime.date(2009, 10, 22), 
                  'id': 13, 'email': u'user@mail.com'}]}
```

In forms.py I have the following code:

```
class PersonalInfoForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_details = kwargs.pop('user_details', None)
        super(PersonalInfoForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)

    username = forms.CharField(required=True, initial=user_details[0]['username'])
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
```

And I get the following error:

```
name 'user_details' is not defined
```

I tried accessing it with `self.user_details` and only `user_details` and it gives me the same error

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`user_details` is passed to `__init__`, so is not defined outside of it. That's why you can't access it when you're instatiating that CharField object. Set `initial` in `__init__` itself, after you've popped it from kwargs, for instance:

```
class PersonalInfoForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_details = kwargs.pop('user_details', None)
        super(PersonalInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user_details:
            self.fields['username'].initial = user_details[0]['username']
```

When you get a chance, consider reading up on [scopes in python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: +1 beautiful. 10 seconds before submitting my very similar solution, the orange banner pops up...nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

Can you explain in a more clear way what you are trying to do? I believe what you are doing is unnecessary. Not sure if I understood you, but take a look at Django Model Forms: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

```
>>> from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create the form class.
>>> class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...         model = Article

# Creating a form to add an article.
>>> form = ArticleForm()

# Creating a form to change an existing article.
>>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

If it's what you are looking for, you could easily addapt to use your user model. Remember, you can pick which fields you want to allow to be changed. The `instance` parameter sets the initial field values (which is what I understood you want to do). The example above will show all fields, the below example shows how to display only 2 fields.

```
class PartialAuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title')
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: I am trying to access variables from **kwargs in the Forms class.

Comment: Yes. It gives me name 'kwargs' is not defined