# django form queryset filter by current user

Tags: django, forms

I have made a search form like this where user can filter the news accroding to published date and the crawlers that they have selected previously.. Here is my form

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
pub_date_from = forms.CharField(label="From",max_length=20)
pub_date_to = forms.CharField(label="To",max_length=30)
crawler = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Crawler",queryset=Crawler.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
```

Here I want the crawler to be shown only the user have selected previously..

Here is my view..

```
class SingleNewsView(ListView):
model = News
form_class = SearchForm
template_name = "single_news.html"

# def post(self, request, **kwargs):
#   print "request"
#   form = SearchForm(request.user)



def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):

    #form = SearchForm(request.user)
    self.pk = pk

    self.pub_from = request.GET.get('pub_date_from',False)
    self.pub_to = request.GET.get('pub_date_to',False)
    self.crawlers = request.GET.get('crawler',False)
    self.format = request.GET.get('format',False)
    print self.format

    print self.crawlers


    return super(SingleNewsView,self).get(request,pk, **kwargs)



def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(SingleNewsView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["form"] = SearchForm
    if self.pub_from and self.pub_to and self.crawlers:
        qs = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk).filter(published_date__range=(self.pub_from,self.pub_to), crawler=self.crawlers)
    else:
        qs = News.objects.filter(category_id=self.pk)

    context["something"] = qs
    self.request.session['something_pks'] = [ i.details for i in qs ]

    return context
```

How can I get the current user in form and filter according to current user.. Need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the user to form in view as keyword argument.

Just don't pass it on in form init method. Check out this post:

[Passing **kwargs to Django Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993014/passing-kwargs-to-django-form)

you hand over request.user just like user_details are passed into form in that example.

Comment: In my view where can I pass user to form ??

Comment: context["form"] = SearchForm(user = request.user) would be good place to start. Did you look at the page i added to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your best option is to declare the variable before `__init__`, 
# and then set the variable to a form field inside `__init__`:

from django import forms


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    location = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Locations.objects.filter(user=kwargs.pop('user', None)))

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


# In your class-based view pass self.request.user
# or in a function-based view pass request.user:
def MyView(request)
    MyForm(user=request.user)
```